# how to aggregate KQL result lines in a list

Tags: kql

I am trying to create a list of users/notebooks since our cmdb seems to be corrupted and I am trying to utilize the defender to do so.
It works okay, but in cases with multiple users using a device I would like to aggregate the lines for a single notebook into one and just have a list of users

```
// I am utilizing the device info table
DeviceInfo 
// select the kind of devices I need by regex
| where DeviceName matches regex "md\\d{6}"
// filter for those recently updated
| where Timestamp > ago(30d)
// and need to apply the following to deal with usernames sometimes listed with uppercase/lowercase and remove empty lines (as far as looged on users are concerned)
| distinct DeviceName, a = tolower(tostring(LoggedOnUsers)) 
| where a != "[]"`
```

now, for those cases coming up as

```
MD123456, user1
MD123456, user2
MD123456, user3
```

I would like to compress the result to

```
MD123456, [user1,user2,user3]
```

I assumed `make_list()`/`make_set()` might be an option, but the available documentation doesn't really help me in that case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you *can* use the [`make_set()` aggregation function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/makeset-aggfunction).

for example:

```
DeviceInfo 
| where Timestamp > ago(30d)
| where DeviceName matches regex "md\\d{6}"
| extend user = tolower(tostring(LoggedOnUsers))
| where user != "[]"
| summarize make_set(user) by DeviceName
```